# Windows 8: including other javascript sources without HTML

Tags: javascript, windows-8

I am writing a [Background Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977045.aspx) in a Windows 8 JS app, and I want the Background Task to be able to use Javascript defined in other files (the [WinJS.log()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj150612.aspx) function, etc...) Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to include other Javascript sources in a single .`js` file, and since this javascript file is invoked through the [BackgroundTaskBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundtaskbuilder.aspx), there's no corresponding `.html` file in which I can put `<script src=...></script>` tags to include further `.js` sources.

Does anyone else have an idea on how I can include code in a Background task? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that background tasks are basically WebWorkers.

Because of this you can use the 'importScripts' function, which will allow you to add scripts and make their contents available to you.

Note, the WebWorker environment isn't the same as a full browser. Details here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/